# Exibir mensagem diferente em caso de timeout

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma aplicação *web* em *PHP* onde gero um conjunto de faturas. Esse processamento é feito de acordo com o dia de vencimento. Como alguns dias levam mais tempo para finalizar que outros, pode ocorrer ***timeout***.

Por ser um sistema legado, ***não posso aumentar mais o tempo máximo de execução*** (*set_time_limit*).

Quando isso ocorre, exibo a mensagem genérica de *"Erro de processamento"*, o que não deixa claro ao usuário que o problema foi o tempo de execução muito longo.

Como posso controlar para **exibir uma mensagem** diferente em caso de ***timeout***?
Idealmente em *Javascript*, seria possível?

Comment: A solução ideal seria você ter um processo ou servidor separados que ficarão consumindo assincronamente esses _jobs_ que são lentos demais para serem processados em uma única requisição, e depois que eles forem processados avisar o usuário sobre o resultado.
Como é um sistema legado, não sei se esse tipo de alteração seria possível no seu caso. [Essa resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/858924/1284458) tem alguns exemplos caso seja de alguma ajuda.

Comment: Acho que depende de como isso é feito. A grosso modo o PHP só serve pra renderizar a página, ou seja, se o processamento atrasa a "entrega" da página (fica processando por muito tempo), acho que uma solução via JS seria melhor, de forma assíncrona, e o usuário não fica achando que a página ou o site travou.

Comment: Vc já tentou capturar esse erro com try catch ? No JS mesmo ? Se vc conseguir capturar esse erro, vc pode exibir uma mensagem customizada para o seu usuario, já que me parece que o seu problema é o usuario saber oque aconteceu..

Comment: @MatheusBarbosa tentei sim mas sem sucesso.. nenhum dos controles de try catch pegou meu retorno.. (nem demorando o tempo real nem simulando com um _evento de retorno_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chame via AJAX o arquivo PHP que faz esse processamento, e então analise o código de status HTTP da resposta para verificar se ocorreu *timeout*:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'processamento.php',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        // código normal
    },
    error: function(error) {
        if (error.status == '408' || error.status == '504') {
            alert('Tempo esgotado! Processamento tomou mais tempo do que o permitido');
        }
    }
});
```

---

Apenas ilustrando, o código [**408**](https://www.checkupdown.com/status/E408_pt.html) indica que o servidor está processando por muito tempo a requisição, enquanto o [**504**](https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/erro-504-gateway-timeout-wordpress/) indica que pode haver erro ou inexistência do *server*.

Comment: Massa, @Edson. Só adicionei uns _links_ pra quem quiser ver o que são os códigos mas esse controle em resolve o problema!!

Answer (score 0):

O ideal mesmo seria você colocar essas faturas em uma fila e ir processando de forma assincrona.

Mas como é um sistema legado e talvez você não possa fazer essa alteração, para capturar o erro de timeout você pode trabalhar com a função [register_shutdown_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

Segue exemplo:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "0"); // ocultando mensagens de erro
set_time_limit(3); // setando tempo máximo de execução para 3 segundos

class Fatura {    
    public function __construct() {
        // registrando função que vai ser chamada quando o script for finalizado (com sucesso ou não)
        register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'shutdown'));
    }

    private function shutdown() {
        $error = error_get_last();
        if ($error !== null) { // verificando se ocorreu algum erro durante a execução
            $message = $error["message"];
            if (strpos($message, "Maximum execution time") !== false) {
                die(json_encode(array("success" => false, "msg" => "Tempo máximo de execução foi excedido.")));
            }

            die(json_encode(array("success" => false, "msg" => "Desculpe, não foi possível finalizar o processamento.")));
        }
    }

    public function gerar() {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
            echo "Gerando fatura $i<br/>";
            sleep(1);
        } 
        die(json_encode(array("success" => true)));
    }
}

$fatura = new Fatura();
$fatura->gerar();
```

Comment: Vlw pela resposta, diego. Tentei usar mas percebi que não tenho tanto acesso assim ao php do site.. preciso tentar algo via _JS_ =/